# Finding GCD of two polynomials over a ring

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to find the GCD of the two polynomials below over the ring GF(2)[x] and I'm having some trouble. The steps I did are below:

**p(x) = x<sup>12</sup> + x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x + 1**

**q(x) = x<sup>11</sup> + x<sup>10</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>5</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1**

So, when I do p(x) / q(x) I get: **x - 1** with a remainder of **x<sup>10</sup> + x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> - x<sup>7</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 2**

I then take q(x) and divide by that remainder which gives me: **x** with a remainder of **-x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> - x<sup>7</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> - 2x + 1**

Then, I do **(-x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> - x<sup>7</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> - 2x + 1)** / **(x<sup>10</sup> + x<sup>9</sup> + x<sup>8</sup> - x<sup>7</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>4</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 2)** = **-x - 2** with a remainder of **2x<sup>8</sup> - 2x<sup>7</sup> + 3x<sup>6</sup> + 2x<sup>4</sup> + 3x<sup>3</sup> - 2x<sup>2</sup> - 3x + 4**

Now continuing this process gives me fractions which I know is not right, but I also know it isn't right that I have coefficients of **2** and greater when I divide by **q(x)** by the first remainder since it's over the ring GF(2). So what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to do all computations mod 2.

Comment: Forgot all about that part. Thanks. Doing them all now and checking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another point of view is that over $\mathbb{F}_2$ both polynomials are reducible, and the Berlekamp factorisation algorithm quickly gives that
\begin{align*}
p(x) & = (x^7 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x^5 + x^2 + 1)\\
q(x) & = (x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^5 + x^2 + 1),
\end{align*}
so that $gcd(p,q)=x^5+x^2+1$.

Comment: I  would  like  to  learn    the  Berlekamp  factorization  algorithm .  Could  you  suggest  some  books  $?$

Comment: You will find it in any book on computer algebra; see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) for references, e.g., in the book of [Joachim von zur Gathen](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/computer-science/algorithmics-complexity-computer-algebra-and-computational-g/modern-computer-algebra-3rd-edition).